# How to make sure a function is called by on thread at a time?

Tags: multithreading

I have two threads A and B and some shared data Data. Both threads will call a function f(), which will fist read the data and then modify the data. Both ReadData() and ModifyData() are thread safe, implemented with mutex.

```
f(){
ReadData()
ModifyData()
}
```

I want f() to be called by only one thread at a time, or I want ReadData() and ModifyData() to be called as a whole.How do I achieve this? One way I think is to acquire a lock after entering f and release the lock after exiting f.

Comment: Any answer is going to be language-specific.  What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using C++ @AndrewHenle